# How do i print the variable if i dont exactly know its name?

Tags: python

For example, If i had code similar to this:

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
x3 = 3

for i in range(3):
  #How do i get "x" + i and print the variable's value?
  print()
```

Comment: You put it into a data structure such as a list. The point of variable names is for your convenience while programming. If it's not convenient, don't use it.

Comment: If you need to access variables dynamically, you should be using either a list or a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate through the numbered variables without the use of an array, 
you can use `locals()`:

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
x3 = 3

for i in range(1,4): # Note that it's range(1,4) if you want 1, 2, 3
  print(locals()[f"x{i}"])
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

not a huge amount of information about what you're asking here, but I think the below solves the it

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
x3 = 3
    
lst = [x1,x2,x3]

for i in lst:
  print(i)
```

output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: I didn't know you could put variables in lists. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `eval` function:

```
x1, x2, x3 = 1, 2, 3
for i in range(1,4):
  print(eval("x"+str(i)))
```

Output:

```
% python3 script.py
1
2
3
```

Comment: Please consider the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/13552470

Comment: Thanks for the link, very interesting! I made some performance tests and `locals()[f"x{i}"]` is actually ~15 times faster than `eval("x"+str(i))`.